# LINQ to SQL: retrieve data and put it in a textBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm kinda new to LINQ, so sorry if my question is dumb.

I need to retrieve some values from a database and put them in textBoxes. Just that. Something like the code below, but using LINQ:

EDIT: actually, I want to retrieve more than one field. Like that:

```
SqlDataReader dr = new functionThatReturnsDataReader();
if (dr.HasRows) {
    dr.Read();

    txtId = dr["Id"].ToString();
    txtName = dr["Name"].ToString();
}
```

I've found [this solution online](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Aug/24/LINQ-To-Sql-Getting-a-Command-Object-from-a-Query):

```
IDbCommand command = dc.GetCommand(query);
command.Connection = dc.Connection;
command.Connection.Open();
IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

However, it seems like I'm trowing away everything that LINQ stands for if I mix it with a standard executeReader. There's no reason in building a data context and query and them execute them like ADO...

How can I achieve the same without using IDbCommand and IDataReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a LINQ to SQL class from your database:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx

Then you can treat the database table like an object and query it with linq... without the specifics of the query you are trying to run, I cannot construct the linq query for you, but creating the DBML file is the first step.

Comment: Thanks for the link, man, but the query is working fine... I just don't know a good way to get all the records that my query returns and put them into textBoxes.

Comment: If you use linq, you can [DataBind via the use of a helper](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9251ed60-96b4-47f3-a85a-f2c82884e354/simple-data-binding-to-textbox) or simply iterate over the results

Answer (score 1):

One thing to think about when comparing a LINQ (or Entity Framework, or other ORM) solution to an ADO.NET solution is that the ORM's are--generally--strongly typed. This means that you need to apply object-oriented principles to them.

If you're dealing with the context, query, and results all in the same function, you can do this:

```
using(var context = new YourContext())
{
    txtId.Text = (from t in context.YourTable
                  where t.Conditions
                  select t.Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If they're not in the same function (and really, they shouldn't be), then something like this would work:

```
string FunctionThatReturnsId()
{
    using(var context = new YourContext())
    {
        return (from t in context.YourTable
                      where t.Conditions
                      select t.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

...

txtId.Text = FunctionThatReturnsId();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough... I need to retrieve more than one field. I could use your code and return an object instead of a string, but I already have a data context, I'm not sure that the best way is to create another typed object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity Framework then you dont need any query just write id in text box and hit search button it will show you all records in text box of that id.

```
      EntityFramework_mvcEntities db = new EntityFramework_mvcEntities();


        int i =Convert.ToInt32( txtsrch.Text);
        Employee p = db.Employees.Find(i);



        TextBox1.Text = p.Name;
         TextBox2.Text = p.Email;
        TextBox4.Text = p.Mobile;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var q = from c in context.GetTable<tbl_user>()
    where c.user_ID == lbuserid.Text.ToString()
    select new
    {
        c.Username,
        c.firstname
    };

foreach (var item in q)
{
    lbusername.Text = item.Username;
    lbfirstname.Text = item.firstname;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation about why/how your code/answer should work?

Comment: firstly, get the data from sql and store in variable q, afterward we use loop(foreach) to read all the data in variable q one by one